# Kubernetes kubectl view config

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

if i apply some config to kubernetes with kubectl like:

```
kubectl apply -f config.yaml
```

Is there any command to read or show this config? I need update some things in config, but I'm on another pc and I dont have configs here, so I need get them from kubectl first, is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- simple way : cat the file

```
cat config.yaml
```

- indirect way:

```
kubectl apply -f config.yaml --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

- for brevity

```
kubectl create -f config.yaml --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy ~/.kube/config from one machine to another, you can then access your cluster using kubectl on the other machine. From there you can do `kubectl get configmap <name> -o yaml > config.yaml`, edit the saved config.yaml and re-apply with `kubectl apply -f config.yaml`.